# Reflection with object assignment

Tags: c#, .net

Why is this code printing "" instead of "newname"? I thought all objects are references. What am I missing here?

I know I could use info[0].SetValue .. but I am doing the same with a Property which holds an array of objects and I want to get 1 object and give it a new value.

```
    private void ()
    {
        A var1 = new A() { holder = new B() { name = "" }  };

        PropertyInfo[] info = var1.GetType().GetProperties();

        object obj1 = info[0].GetValue(var1); // this returns me A.holder object 

        B var2 = new B() { name = "newname" };

        obj1 = (object)var2; 

        Console.WriteLine(var1.holder.name);

    }

    public class B
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public B holder { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT: ok, i think i got my problem

assigning obj1 a new reference, doenst change the reference of var1.holder.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect it to print "newname"?

Comment: `obj1 = (object)var2;` just changes the object that the `obj1` variable points to. It doesn't modify the object that `obj1` previously pointed to. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: cause i assign the variable obj1 the reference to (object) var2

Comment: ok sorry this is a bad example, give me a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To annotate your code:

```
// create a new A object in memory and a variable called var1 that points to it
A var1 = new A() { name = "" };

// get the list of properties on the A class
PropertyInfo[] info = var1.GetType().GetProperties();

// create a variable called obj1 that points to the value of 
// the first property on the A object created above (I.e. the empty string ""),
object obj1 = info[0].GetValue(var1);

// create a new A object in memory and a variable called var2 that points to it
A var2 = new A() { name = "newname" };

// change the variable obj1 to point to the new A object 
// instead of the string it previously pointed to
obj1 = (object)var2;

// print the name property of the first A, which has not changed since creation
Console.WriteLine(var1.name);
```

So you can see that nowhere does the value of the property `var1.name` actually change.

Answer (score 0):

You have the assignment

```
A var1 = new A() { name = "" };
```

and nothing runs after that which changes the value of name in var1 and therefore the Console prints ""